# AZURE - Not able to upload file to a file system with SAS Authentication

Tags: java, azure

I'm trying to upload a file to Azure File system using a Shared Access Signature using Postman and Curl, but it is returning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code>
    <Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:51beb8e2-001a-00ab-3731-78763f000000
Time:2017-12-18T18:52:03.5526162Z</Message>
    <HeaderName>Content-Length</HeaderName>
    <HeaderValue>28415</HeaderValue>
</Error>
```

I did all the change using Content-Length = 0 and x-ms-content-length: 28415 but it is returning the same error.

Any suggestion about this?

Thanks

Comment: well, at least share the request you are sending?

Comment: Please provide your relevant screenshots and request messages to let me help you.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. I solved that sending a Content-Lenght: 0 before x-ms-content-lenght and the upload worked fine.